# Подключить postgres docker к symfony5

Tags: postgresql, symfony, docker-compose

С докер на Вы, да и симфони в общем то тоже.

в docker-compose.yml

```
services:
manager-nginx:
    image: .../repo:nginx
    volumes:
    - ./:/app
    depends_on:
        - manager-php-fpm
    ports:
        - "8080:80"

manager-php-fpm:
    image: .../repo:fpm
    volumes:
        - ./:/app
    environment: 
        APP_DEBUG: 1     
    depends_on:
        - manager-postgres 
manager-postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - manager-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    environment: 
        POSTGRES_USER: app
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
        POSTGRES_DB: app
    ports: 
        - 5432:5432          
volumes:
    manager-postgres:
    composer:
```

В файле .env

```
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://app:secret@manager-postgres:5432/app
```

в doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_pgsql' 
    charset: utf8
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

при попытке создать миграцию

In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 73:

```
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "manager-postgres" to address:   
  Name or service not known
```

Comment: вы миграцию где создаете? если в локальном терминале, то у вас ясен пень ничего не выйдет, тк manager-postgres — это изнутри докера пути. Миграции надо выполнять из контейнера с php.

Comment: `docker-compose exec manager-php-fpm bin/console d:m:m `

Comment: Да, дошло, спасибо